# SQL Server : calling a stored procedure or not

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure that has one input parameter.

However, in the stored procedure, there is a condition that needs user's input (`WHEN t.flag = 0`).

Is there a way not to call a new stored procedure but does the same job?

I do not want to add another input parameter in `[dbo].[UpdateTheRate]`
itself because I have other processes going on in this stored procedure.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[UpdateTheRate] (@PID int)
AS
    UPDATE t
    SET t.rate = 
            CASE 
               WHEN t.flag = 1 THEN (select UnitRate 
                                     from RateTable 
                                     where state ='IL' and Term='20')
               WHEN t.flag = 0 THEN EXEC [dbo.rate_procedure]  --(USER enter rate)
    FROM TblChargeTable t
    WHERE t.PID = @PID
```

Comment: You can call a function there but not a stored procedure. There are hacks that might work for you but that's probably not a road you want to go down. And I'm not sure what you mean by "user's input".

Comment: @shawnt00 you can all another stored procedure from within a stored procedure.

Comment: You can't call another stored procedure inside an `update`.

Comment: I understand why you might not want to add additional input parameters but I _don't_ understand why the other processing in this procedure is the reason.

Comment: [dbo].[UpdateTheRate] is actually a long sp and there is another sp calling [dbo].[UpdateTheRate] using @PID.  I only have this small part in the CASE  Statement needs User's input.  It is a VB to call the store procedures.  That is why I have "input parameter"

Comment: You can't prompt for user input inside a stored procedure. I believe you hope to avoid gathering that input until you can determine that your need it. My apologies for being confused but those last two sentences don't make a lot of sense to me. I think you'll have to break this up into pieces.

Comment: so I think the only way is the way you showed me earlier.  I was hoping to see if there was a way not to call another store procedure for user's input.

Comment: There might be ways to pause the stored procedure after it sends back some results and waits for the user interface to receive some input which is dropped into a table and then picked up after the procedure resumes. But you've already said this is multiple procedure calls deep and that would only complicate the design further. I won't say it's impossible but I highly doubt it would be the best idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something along these lines?

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[UpdateTheRate] (@PID int)
AS

-- defer executing the procedure unless necessary
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM TblChargeTable WHERE flag = 0 and PID = @PID)
BEGIN
   EXEC dbo.rate_procedure; -- get @user_rate via return code or out parameters perhaps
END

UPDATE t
SET    t.rate = 
       CASE WHEN t.flag = 1 THEN (select UnitRate from RateTable where state ='IL' and Term='20')
            WHEN t.flag = 0 THEN @user_rate END -- retrieved above
FROM   TblChargeTable t
WHERE  t.PID = @PID;
```